# Sorting Based on Calculated Value in Rails & Sort By Will Pagination Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Submission model which `has_many` Scores. In the Score model, I have score1:float, score2:float, score3:float, score4:float, and score5:float.

Now, I want to sort the Submission based on the weighted total score the Submission had. So, I created a method in submission.rb:

```
  def total_score
    scores.sum('(0.15 * scores.score1) + (0.15 * scores.score2) +
    (0.20 * scores.score3) + (0.25 * scores.score4) + (0.25 * scores.score5)')
  end

  def sorted_by_total_score
    Submission.all.sort_by(&:total_score)
  end
```

Then I called the method to my pages_controller.rb:

```
def score_summary
  @find = Submission.ransack(params[:q])
  @submissions = @find.result.includes(:user, scores: [:admin_user]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50).sorted_by_total_score
end
```

But it got error:

```
undefined method `sorted_by_total_score' for #<Submission::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fdccc156d68>
```

Where did I do wrong? Thank you.

UPDATE: SOLVED by jinth answer.

---

Now, I have another issue with the pagination. Here is the current code in pages_controller.rb:

```
def score_summary
  @find = Submission.ransack(params[:q])
  @submissions = @find.result.includes(:user, scores: [:admin_user]).sort_by{|submission| -submission.total_score}
  @submissions = @submissions.pagination(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
end
```

In the view I put the pagination:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <%= will_paginate @submissions, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code should be working by now however I got this error:

```
NoMethodError in PagesController#score_summary
undefined method `pagination' for #<Array:0x007faef8923548>
```

---

UPDATE: SOLVED

If you have a sort_by in the controller then you will need to put these code into your application_controller.rb to make the pagination works.

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't get why do u need Submission.all again. i guess u need to sort the results only.

```
  @submissions = @find.result.includes(:user, scores: [:admin_user]).sort_by{|submission| submission.total_score}.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
```

if you want in descending order, you can use

```
sort_by{|submission| -submission.total_score}
```

also include 'self' before score calculation

Comment: It works! But it sorted from the lowest score to the highest. How can I sort it by the highest score first? Thank you.

Comment: Also, if I include the pagination, it will got error.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However the pagination still error. It says that the undefined method `pagination' for #<Array:0x007faef7b4d2e8>

Comment: try pagination on the results. like @submissions = @submissions.paginate()

Comment: Still got error, and it says undefined method paginate. If I tried to remove the sort_by, the pagination is working.

Comment: `@submissions = @find.result.includes(:user, scores: [:admin_user]).sort_by{|submission| submission.total_score}
 @submissions = @submissions.paginate()`

Comment: Should I put enter between the first @submissions and the second @submissions(after the sort_by)? If yes, that is what I did and got Undefined method 'paginate'. If no, it results a syntax error.

Comment: second code must be in a new line. something wrong is happening with your code.. it is working fine when i tested .